# Can't scroll UIImageView with AspectFill in UIScrollView and AutoLayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimageview, autolayout

I have a UIScrollView with a single UIImageView child. The scrollView is pinned on all sides to the (root) parent container with autolayout, and the child imageview is also pinned to all sides with content mode set to `AspectFill`.

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"photo1.jpeg"];

_imageView.image = image;
_imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;

_scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointZero;
_scrollView.contentSize = _imageView.image.size;
_scrollView.zoomScale = 1;
```

The image in this case is wider than my screen. When I launch my app, the imageview is correctly displaying the image filling up the screen. However, I can't seem to pan the image left or right. When i zoom in, I can pan, however, I'm unable to pan to the corners of the image.

I feel like my content size is not being computed properly thanks to auto-layout, but I'm not sure which parameters I can play which would allow me to scroll the image to its edges.

I've attached an image below, where you can see that the image can't be scrolled in a way that displays the beginning of 'happiness'. I also uploaded the sample [here](https://github.com/vijaysharm/stackoverflow-31296497)

[image: autolayout]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the child imageview is also pinned to all sides

Instead, turn off auto layout *for the child image view* (set its `translates...` to YES). You are already setting the scroll view's `contentSize` to the image size, so now scrollability will leap into life and will interface correctly with zooming.

Comment: Thanks for the help matt. I just tried what you mentioned, and suddenly the constraint resolver freaks out saying it's unable to satisfy simultaneous constraints. Moreover, it causes my uiimageview to not fill up the scrollview. I uploaded the sample [here](https://github.com/vijaysharm/stackoverflow-31296497). So although with your change, I can indeed scroll to the end of the image, the imageview no longer fills the scrollview.

Comment: Also, matt, is there a way to solve this if I don't set the contentSize?

Comment: "So although with your change, I can indeed scroll to the end of the image, the imageview no longer fills the scrollview" Oh, of course; in the absence of auto layout, you must set the image view's size yourself. And of course you must remove all the constraints that affect the image view (set them as mere placeholders in the nib, if you can't just delete them). But that is exactly what I am advising you to do. — I'll be very happy to fork and pull-request your github project if you can't solve it yourself, but let me first give you a chance to see if my advice makes sense.

Comment: "Also, matt, is there a way to solve this if I don't set the contentSize" You are asking for a pure auto layout solution? I have found that an image view on its own won't work. You'll need a content view surrounding it. See https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/tree/master/bk2ch07p376zoomCentered3/ch20p680zoomCentered for an example.

Comment: Thanks matt. I removed the constraints completely off my uiimageview, set the `translates...` to `YES`, and I set the frame of the uiimageview to something specific, and that seems to work for me. I can understand from your help that turning off auto-layout helps my cause, but is there a way to rationalize why I'm unable to scroll to beginning of my imageview? Am I thinking about this all wrong? I wish I could understand why applying "AspectFill" to my initial problem prevents me from scrolling to the edge of the image?

Comment: Perfect! Glad to hear that this makes sense to you.